# How to refresh the flask web page?

Tags: python, html, flask

Recently, I have a project is to implement the dynamic plotting on a web page.

Here is my python code

```
from flask import Flask
#from flask import render_template
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import io
import base64

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/plot')
def build_plot():

    img = io.BytesIO()

    y = [1,2,3,4,5]
    x = [0,2,1,3,4]
    plt.plot(x,y)
    plt.savefig(img, format='png')
    img.seek(0)

    plot_url = base64.b64encode(img.getvalue()).decode()

    return '<img src="data:image/png;base64,{}">'.format(plot_url)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0')
```

Here is my HTML code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title> Plot</title>
        <meta content='5; url=http://127.0.0.1:5000/plot' http-equiv='refresh'>
    </head>
    <body>
        <img src="data:image/png;base64, {{ plot_url }}">
    </body>
</html>
```

Although I add `<meta content='5; url=http://127.0.0.1:5000/plot' http-equiv='refresh'>` into my HTML code, it still can not refresh automatically.

If I want to observe the change of the plotting, I still need to refresh it manually.

Can anyone help me to solve this problem? Thanks a lot

Comment: You might wanna refer to this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15721679/update-and-render-a-value-from-flask-periodically

Comment: This has nothing to do with Python or Flask. Simplest approach would be using `iframe` within page and regularly updating it, or more advanced (and correct IMHO) to use AJAX. Check the link provided by @LingchaoCao.

Answer (score 7):

You do not need to include the `URL`. Just use only the **content** attribute of `meta` tag.

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5" >
```

But to see the real time changes in your graph, you might want to look at [sockets](https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) in flask. This will help server push changes to all clients using [broadcasting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45486960/what-is-the-best-way-to-update-all-clients-when-flask-database-changes-without-p/45487518#45487518). Using sockets is way better approach than to refresh your page at regular interval.

Comment: But be aware that websockets often does not work behind corporate firewalls. I recommend using AJAX instead.

Comment: Are you sure, refreshing on every X interval to see the changes is good approach? May be pooling is better option. Also there has to be a workaround in corporate firewalls. @AndrejsCainikovs Right? :)

Comment: resource-wise websockets are efficient, access-wise AJAX is the safest. I experience websocket denial at my work, and I suffer in pain quite often. And since all the corporate network is configured properly, I cannot do anything about this. In any case - these are just my 0.02$.

Comment: @AndrejsCainikovs Thank you for the discussion. Got some info from you. Hope this helps everyone. Cheers!!

Comment: Thanks for your advise, I will try these